# Platform Event ID Error

Tags: error-messages, platform-event

I'm getting `INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE - The event can't be published because it contains an ID value.` when logging my platform event errors like so:

```
private static List <Account_Change_Event__e> newaccountChangeEvent = new List <Account_Change_Event__e>();

public static void broadcastAccountEvent(Map<Id, Account> newMap, Map<Id, Account> oldMap) {
List<Account> accsToProvision = new List<Account>();
for (Account acc : newMap.values()) {
    Account oldacc = oldMap.get(acc.Id);
    if(acc.Level__c != oldacc.Level__c) {
        newaccountChangeEvent.add (
            new Account_Change_Event__e (
                    Name__c = acc.Name,
                    Level__c = acc.Level__c,
                )
        );
    }
}

if(!newaccountChangeEvent.isEmpty()) {
    List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(newEventsList);
    for (Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {
            System.debug('Successfully published a platform event.');
        } else {
            for (Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                System.debug('publish Error returned: ' +
                            err.getStatusCode() +
                            ' - ' +
                            err.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The strange parts are: 1) I'm not including an ID in the Platform Event, 2) The logs first show `Successfully published a platform event.` and then logs the above error 3 times in a row.  It seems like it's trying to re-publish or some other behavior that's quite unclear.

Comment: You should include the rest of the code, since I don't think the error message you shared is coming from anything here.

Comment: @NicholasSavini - good call, I've added comparable code, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's in a trigger, my guess is that it's running the logic to publish the events a second time (as you suspected). Your trigger handler likely runs on the before and after events, so perhaps this logic is running both times.

A simple way to prevent this error would be to clear out the list of platform events once you publish them:

```
if(!newaccountChangeEvent.isEmpty()) {
    List<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(newEventsList);
    newEventsList.clear();
    ...
}
```

But this is probably also a symptom of a bigger problem; the code should be protected so that it only runs one time, during the appropriate trigger event.